# Merge two sorted arrays of names into a new array, eliminating duplicates ( C Language )

Tags: arrays, list, merge

I need to merge two sorted files of names into 1 file of names, eliminating any duplicate names.

So for example:

**List 1:**

Ashley

James

Kevin

Zoe

**List 2:**

Evelynn

James

Kalvin

Wayne

**List 3:**

Ashley

Evelynn

James

Kalvin

Kevin

Wayne

Zoe

---

This is what my function looks like so far:

```
void funcmerge(char list1[][10], char list2[][10], char list3[][10])
{

}
```

List1 is the first list of names put into an array of strings

List2 is the second list of names put into an array of strings

List3 is a list of names merged from List1 and List2 without duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest modifying the merge part of merge sort for this solution.  Create two counters, one for each list.  The two counters will hold the current positions for each of their respective arrays.  Then,

- compare the two current elements in each list,
- add the lexicographically smaller element to list3,
- increment the counter of the list which contained the smaller element.
- repeat until the end of an array is reached.
- Add the remainder of the other array to list3.

If the two elements are equal at any time, increment only one of the counters and don't add anything to list3 (this will ensure duplicates are only added once).

```
void funcmerge(char *list1[], char *list2[], char *list3[])
{
    int i = 0, k = 0, cnt = 0;

    // while both lists still contain elements
    while(list1[i] && list2[k]){
        int cmp = strcmp(list1[i], list2[k]);

        // if the names are equal, don't add anything to the list
        if (cmp == 0){
            k++;

        } else if (cmp < 0){
            list3[cnt++] = list1[i++];

        } else {
            list3[cnt++] = list2[k++];
        }
    }


    // if list1 still has elements, finish adding it to the list
    if (list1[i]){
        while (list1[i]){
            if (strcmp(list3[cnt - 1], list1[i])){
                list3[cnt++] = list1[i++];

            } else{
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    // if list2 still has elements, finish adding it to the list
    if (list2[k]){
        while(list2[k]){
            if (strcmp(list3[cnt - 1], list2[k])){
                list3[cnt++] = list2[k++];

            } else{
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, you should note that I changed the signature of you function, and I implemented this algorithm assuming that the array ends with a null character.  i.e,

```
 char *list1[] = {"Ashley", "James", "Kevin", "Zoe", '\0'};
 char *list2[] = {"Evelynn", "James", "Kalvin", "Wayne", '\0'};
```

If the lists do not end in a null character, you will either need to hardcode the arrays length into your code (which I don't suggest), or pass in another two parameters with the lengths of the two arrays.

Lastly, you will also need to get the size of list3.  I can think of two way to go about that.  One method is to return the size of list3.  Simply add `return cnt;` to the end of the function.  Or two, set the entire array to null beforehand (I would use `memset()`).  Then, you can traverse the array until you hit a null element.